# Ignoring specific fields when using "with" on a C# 9 record?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0, c#-record-type

When creating a new instance of a C# 9 `record` by using the `with` keyword, I'd like to ignore some fields instead of copying them into the new instance too.

In the following example, I have a `Hash` property. Because it is very expensive in computation, it is only computed when needed and then cached (I have a deeply immutable record, so that hash will never change for an instance).

```cs
public record MyRecord {

   // All truely immutable properties
   public int ThisAndManyMoreComplicatedProperties { get; init; } 
   // ...

   // Compute only when required, but then cache it
   public string Hash {
      get {
         if (hash == null)
            hash = ComputeHash();
         return hash;
      }
   }

   private string? hash = null;
}
```

When calling

```cs
MyRecord myRecord = ...;
var changedRecord = myRecord with { AnyProp = ... };
```

`changedRecord` contains the `hash` value from `myRecord`, but what I want to have is the default value `null` again.

Any chance to mark the `hash` field as "transient"/"internal"/"reallyprivate"..., or do I have to write my own copy-constructor to mimic this feature?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that there's nothing built-in for that and that [writing your own copy constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression) is the intended solution for this use case.

Comment: I kinda didn't really understand your requirement.. When `with` clones the record the new record will get the existing hash (and it's a clone, so it should hash the same) not by running the hash again but just by copy of the value (so it's cheap) but then surely your setter for AnyProp (because it's changing the record hence the hash) will set the hash null again so it will be calc'd next time it's asked for (factoring the new value of AnyProp) and the copy constructor will use the AnyProp setter to give a new value to AnyProp, thereby nulling hash.. ?

Comment: @CaiusJard there is possibility that hash was not calculated.

Comment: But OP said that *"changedRecord contains the hash value from myRecord"* which it could only reasonably do if it had been calc'd/wasn't null?

Comment: @CaiusJard yep, misunderstood that. OP states that he has " a deeply immutable record", so I think `AnyProp` is a `init` property, thus there is nothing what will reset hash on it's change.

Comment: @Andi more details about this caching hashing (heyy... ;) ) mechanism please

Comment: My goal is to leave the other properties untouched. I do not want to override the init methods, but I want to work this out-of-the-box. There are potentially a high number of record classes extending this base record and using this hashing mechanism.
The ComputeHash() method could for example convert the whole object into JSON and then SHA256-hash the JSON string (just to give some example).

Comment: @CaiusJard Hashing is just an example use case and not the topic of this question. In my case, I compute a SHA256 hash on a compact JSON-serialized representation of the record (exluding the Hash property itself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround: You can (ab)use inheritance to split the copy constructor in two parts: A manual one only for `hash` (in the base class) and an auto-generated one in the derived class copying all your valuable data fields.

This has the additional advantage of abstracting away your hash (non-)caching logic. Here's a minimal example ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gbLjvX)):

```
abstract record HashableRecord
{
    protected string hash;
    protected abstract string CalculateHash();
    
    public string Hash 
    {
        get
        {
            if (hash == null)
            {
                hash = CalculateHash(); // do expensive stuff here
                Console.WriteLine($"Calculating hash {hash}");
            }
            return hash;
        }
    }
    
    // Empty copy constructor, because we explicitly *don't* want
    // to copy hash.
    public HashableRecord(HashableRecord other) { }
}

record Data : HashableRecord
{
    public string Value1 { get; init; }
    public string Value2 { get; init; }

    protected override string CalculateHash() 
        => hash = Value1 + Value2; // do expensive stuff here
}

public static void Main()
{
    var a = new Data { Value1 = "A", Value2 = "A" };
    
    // outputs:
    // Calculating hash AA
    // AA
    Console.WriteLine(a.Hash);

    var b = a with { Value2 = "B" };
    
    // outputs:
    // AA
    // Calculating hash AB
    // AB
    Console.WriteLine(a.Hash);
    Console.WriteLine(b.Hash);
}
```

Comment: And I would not say that this is "abuse" of inheritance. Abstracting away the hashing is indeed an advantage.

Comment: Here is a testcase fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/usoupq

Comment: @Andi: Nice, thanks for fleshing out the details!

Comment: I came across a bug in this implementation. Auto-generated Equals(HashableRecord?) does not work out of the box, I guess because the hash-field is checked too which may probably not be set already. A workaround seems to be to override Equals(HashableRecord) by:
"public virtual bool Equals(HashableRecord? other) => other != null;"
(just returning true may also work, but my Newtonsoft.JSON serializer threw a NullReferenceException then). Plus "public override int GetHashCode() => 0;"

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround for my problem. This does *not* solve the general problem, and it has another disadvantage: I have to cache the last state of the object, until the hash was recomputed. I understand this is a tradeoff between a potentially heavy computation and higher memory usage.

The trick is to remember the last object reference when the hash was computed. When calling the `Hash` property again, I check if meanwhile the object reference has been changed (i.e. if a new object was created).

```cs
public string Hash {
   get {
      if (hash == null || false == ReferenceEquals(this, hashRef)) {
         hash = ComputeHash();
         hashRef = this;
      }
      return hash;
   }
}
private string? hash = null;
private MyRecord? hashRef = null;
```

I'm still looking for a better solution.

EDIT: I recommend [Heinzi's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66151756/518491)!

Answer (score 1):

I think the only built-in mechanism to allow this is the "copy constructor". As documented in [this post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#with-expressions):

> A record implicitly defines a protected “copy constructor” – a constructor that takes an existing record object and copies it field by field to the new one...

The "copy constructor" is just a constructor that receives an instance of the same type of the record as an argument. If you just implement this constructor you can override the default behavior of the `with` expression. I've made a test based on your code, here's the record declaration:

```cs
public record MyRecord
{
    protected MyRecord(MyRecord original)
    {
        ThisAndMayMoreComplicatedProperties = original.ThisAndMayMoreComplicatedProperties;
        hash = null;
    }

    public int ThisAndMayMoreComplicatedProperties { get; init; }

    string? hash = null;
    public string Hash
    {
        get
        {
            if (hash is null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The stored hash is currently null.");
            }
            return hash ??= ComputeHash();
        }
    }

    string ComputeHash() => "".PadLeft(100, 'A');
}
```

Notice that when I call the property getter I check if the `hash` is null and print a message. Then I've made a little program to check:

```cs
var record = new MyRecord { ThisAndMayMoreComplicatedProperties = 100 };
Console.WriteLine($"{record.Hash}");

var newRecord = record with { ThisAndMayMoreComplicatedProperties = 200 };
Console.WriteLine($"{newRecord.Hash}");
```

If you run this you notice that both calls to `Hash` will print the message that the private `hash` is null. If you comment the copy constructor you'll see that only the first call prints the null.

So I think this solves your problem. The downside of this method is that you have to manually copy every property of your record, which can be pretty annoying. If you record has lots of properties you can use Reflection to iterate over then and copy only the ones you want. You may also define a custom `Attribute` to mark ignoring fields. But bear in my mind that using Reflection always have processing overhead.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see with [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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) decompilation the `with` call is translated into `<Clone>$()` method call which internally calls copy constructor generated by compiler, so you need to define your own [copy constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records#copy-and-clone-members) to prevent `Hash` being called.

Also as the `with` keyword [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression) states:

> If you need to customize the record copy semantics, explicitly declare a copy constructor with the desired behavior.

Answer (score -3):

If I'm understanding you correctly you want to create a new MyRecord object with some of the properties of an existing MyRecord object?

I think something along these lines should work:

```
MyRecord myRecord = ...;
var changedRecord = new MyRecord with { AnyProp = myRecord.AnyProp... };
```