# How to use "with" keyword in a copy constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, language-specifications

Not long ago I got familiar with [with operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69616749/what-is-the-with-operator-for-in-c).
Based on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression), when using the "with expression", reference types will be copied, but that logic can be changed by overriding copy constructor.

> In the case of a reference-type member, only the reference to a member instance is copied when an operand is copied. Both the copy and original operand have access to the same reference-type instance. If you need to customize the record copy semantics, explicitly declare a copy constructor with the desired behavior.

This is how copy logic can be changed:

```
record WithOperatorTest()
{
    private int _myPrivateField;

    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public List<int> MyReferenceTypeProperty { get; set; }

    protected WithOperatorTest(WithOperatorTest original)
    {
        _myPrivateField = original._myPrivateField;
        MyPublicField = original.MyPublicField;
        MyProperty = original.MyProperty;
        // Creating new reference
        MyReferenceTypeProperty = new List<int>(original.MyReferenceTypeProperty);
    }
}
```

I wonder if it's somehow possible to use "with" operator inside a copy constructor to not write unnecessary code & use benefits of the operator to override only the logic that needs to be overridden?
I'd love to achieve a behavior like this:

```
protected WithOperatorTest(WithOperatorTest original)
{
    return original with { MyReferenceTypeProperty = new List<int>(original.MyReferenceTypeProperty) };
}
```

Or:

```
protected WithOperatorTest(WithOperatorTest original)
{
   this = original with { MyReferenceTypeProperty = new List<int>(original.MyReferenceTypeProperty) };
}
```

Or:

```
protected WithOperatorTest(WithOperatorTest original) with
{
    MyReferenceTypeProperty = new List<int>(original.MyReferenceTypeProperty);
}
```

All the attempts above, of course, do not compile. My question is whether the is currently a way to achieve the desired behavior or we need to write copy constructors in "the old way"?

Comment: Unfortunately, I only know of an ugly workaround, not of a "nice" solution: The workaround would be to split your class into a base class (containing the fields you want copied) and a derived class (containing the fields you want to handle separately) and only override the copy constructor in the derived class. A similar example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66151756/87698

Comment: @Heinzi, thanks for sharing. Definately a possible solution, but yeah I am seeking for something more elegant, without the necessity to inherit from some other class. Most probably, there's no such feature in C# yet, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's kind of circular. You need the copy constructor for `with` to work. Therefore, you cannot implement the copy constructor in terms of `with` because then nobody actually provides an implementation.

Comment: @DavidOganov if you use sharplab.io to see the generated code you'll see that `with` calls the generated `Clone` method which in turn calls the copy constructor. If you used `with` in your copy constructor you'll end up with infinite recursion

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ,  PanagiotisKanavos, good points guys. Thank you. I believe for this to work there should be some syntax sugar in the language, which is not there yet :/